# An explicit cast for narrowing numeric conversions

Tags: c++, c++14, casting

Inspired by [gsl::narrow_cast](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/gsl_util#L95), I created my own implementation with the addition of a couple of features:

- a static assert on the types to ensure the cast is actually narrowing (if future changes to the code mean the cast is no longer narrowing, we don't want to still have a `narrow_cast` there)
- the version without a runtime check still has an assert, so it's checked in debug mode

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

namespace details {

template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool is_same_signedness = std::is_signed<T>::value == std::is_signed<U>::value;

template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool can_fully_represent =
    std::is_same<T, U>::value ||
    ( std::is_integral<T>::value && std::is_integral<U>::value &&
        ( ( std::is_signed<T>::value && sizeof(T) >  sizeof(U) ) ||
          ( is_same_signedness<T, U> && sizeof(T) >= sizeof(U) ) ) ) ||
    ( std::is_floating_point<T>::value && std::is_floating_point<U>::value && sizeof(T) >= sizeof(U) );

template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool static_cast_changes_value(U u) noexcept
{
    const auto t = static_cast<T>(u);

    // this should catch most cases, but may miss dodgy unsigned to signed conversion or vice-versa
    if (static_cast<U>(t) != u)
        return true;

    if (std::is_signed<T>::value != std::is_signed<U>::value && ((t < T{}) != (u < U{})))
        return true;

    return false;
}

} // namespace details

// TODO: unchecked cast for types where some loss of precision (and therefore assertion failure) is expected?
template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr T narrow_cast(U&& u) noexcept
{
    static_assert(!details::can_fully_represent<T, U>, "we shouldn't be using narrow_cast for casts that aren't actually narrowing");
    assert(!details::static_cast_changes_value<T>(u));
    return static_cast<T>(std::forward<U>(u));
}

struct narrowing_error : public std::exception {};

template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr T narrow_cast_checked(U u)
{
    static_assert(!details::can_fully_represent<T, U>, "we shouldn't be using narrow_cast for casts that aren't actually narrowing");
    if (details::static_cast_changes_value<T>(u))
        throw narrowing_error();

    return static_cast<T>(u);
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to disallow non-narrowing uses of `narrow_cast<>()`? Consider that your `narrow_cast<>()` might be used in templates that want to allow safe narrowing of values, but might be instantiated with types such that it doesn't actually narrow. Then the use of that template will result in a compile-time error, unless it does something like `if constexpr (is_narrower<T, U>()) t = narrow_cast<T>(u); else t = u;`

Comment: I considered that case, but I would like to be able to remove as many narrow casts as possible by changing types so the casts are no longer necessary, so the compile-time error is very useful for that. Original I was just going to stick with `static_cast` for that situation, but now I'm thinking it might be useful to have a `maybe_narrow_cast` to retain the runtime assert.

Comment: Are you sure this code is intended to be C++11?  You are using C++14 features.

Comment: @L.F. I was compiling with C++14, but when I went to post it I eyeballed it and thought that it was compatible with C++11, but didn't compile to check it. I'll change the tag.

Comment: `static_cast_changes_value()` does not well check value changes.  Fails various corners.  Rather than `T, U, ...`, code would be easier to understand with more descriptive names,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing I noticed: you only support basic arithmetic types (integral and floating point).  This isn't apparent from the name `narrow_cast`.  Either enforce this with a static assert, or provide a mechanism to provide extensions for user defined types.

Here's what you write:

> ```
> template <typename T, typename U>
> constexpr bool can_fully_represent =
>     std::is_same<T, U>::value ||
>     ( std::is_integral<T>::value && std::is_integral<U>::value &&
>         ( ( std::is_signed<T>::value && sizeof(T) >  sizeof(U) ) ||
>           ( is_same_signedness<T, U> && sizeof(T) >= sizeof(U) ) ) ) ||
>     ( std::is_floating_point<T>::value && std::is_floating_point<U>::value && sizeof(T) >= sizeof(U) );
> ```

Here's what I think should be sufficient:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool can_fully_represent =
       std::numeric_limits<T>::min() <= std::numeric_limits<U>::min()
    && std::numeric_limits<T>::max() >= std::numeric_limits<U>::max();
```

OK, maybe I overlooked some edge cases, but that's the idea.

The unchecked version uses a forwarding reference, whereas the check version does not.  Try to keep the interface consistent.

`std::is_same<T, U>::value` can be simplified to `std::is_same_v<T, U>`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I agree with all of them, except that until I upgrade to C++17, I can't use the `_v` helpers.

Comment: @JohnIlacqua Even if you can’t use _v, you can use is_same<T, U>{}.

Comment: I've used the braced syntax for type traits elsewhere in our codebase and gotten complaints from coworkers using MSVC that it doesn't compile. It'll accept `is_same<T, U>{}()` (it seems the implicit conversion to bool doesn't work for them?), but I think that's worse than `::value`.

Comment: @JohnIlacqua OK, that sounds like a bug.  You can ask a question on Stack Overflow to include the details.  Don't forget to post a minimal reproducible example :)

Comment: I decided to preempt the inevitable SO answer of "looks like an MSVC bug, file a bug report', and just filed a bug report: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/793780/msvc-sometimes-fails-to-implicitly-convert-type-tr.html

Comment: @JohnIlacqua: Don't use that after you upgrade either - as you don't want to force C++17 on whoever uses your code.

Comment: "maybe I overlooked some edge cases," --> yes and that why suggested code is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Another point in addition to @L.F.'s answer: You're defining an `is_same_signedness` value, but then - you're not using it within your `static_cast_changes_value()` function, although you could.

Answer (score 2):

Writing portable code is hindered by the `static_assert` that fails when the cast is not actually narrowing.  Some conversions can be narrowing on one platform and not on another.

For example, we know that `std::size_t` is an unsigned type, but its range is implementation-defined.  So when we convert an `unsigned long` to `std::size_t`, that may be a narrowing, widening or exact conversion, depending on the platform.